# Darboux integrability of f-g

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f$ and $g$ are integrable over a closed interval $[a,b]$ what can be said about $(f-g)$? Is it integrable as well? If so can you give me a hint as to how to prove it? Should I use the fact that $\int_{a}^{b} g$ $=-\int_{b}^{a}g, a<b$? I know $(f+g)$ is integrable.

Comment: What's the downvote for may I ask?

Answer (score 3):

You can use same fact for it.

if g is integrable then (-g) is also integrable.
Now, f-g = f+(-g) .

Since, f & (-g) is integrable then f-g is also integrable.

Proof is same as f+g .

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.